# java.lang.ArrayStoreException on List to Array

Tags: java, arrays

When I use the toArray function from Java util I get an ArrayStoreException with no message.
I implemented the absolute same code a year ago in pretty much the same Model and it works there, the query works fine and returns [1,2] from the DB.
here is the code I use:

```
List<?> firstColumn = Base.firstColumn(query, paramList.toArray());
return firstColumn.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

I dont understand why it would not show an Error Message, without it I was lost for days now, hence I turned to you guys, thanks in Advance!

Comment: The elements of `firstColumn` aren't `Integer`s, it would appear.

Comment: The javadoc says *Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects.* ... yeah, so most likely, one ore more objects in `firstColumn` arent integers. Simply iterate that list for example, and print value/type for each entry.

Comment: Refactor firstColumn to a variable, put a debugger after its initialisation and look at whats actually loaded to this list.

Comment: "Refactor firstColumn to a variable" how much more of a variable does it need to be?

Comment: I am really sorry, i just found out that the table i am working with has biginteger for ID's and not integer.......  shall i delete this question as this makes it just a replicate of questions allready asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `firstColumn` list does not contain `Integer` instances. Since you claim that it contains `[1,2]`, probably your list contains `Byte`, `Short`, or `Long` instances. Java will perform some automatic conversions on primitive types, but it does not do that for wrapper objects or arrays. So you have two options:

- Return an array of the correct type:

  ```
  return firstColumn.toArray(new Short[0]); // or Byte[0], or Long[0]
  ```
- Or, if that is not an option, perform the conversion to integers yourself:

  ```
  return firstColumn.stream().map(x -> ((Number)x).intValue()).toArray(Integer[]::new);
  ```

Comment: I actually missed that the ID's of this new table i am working with are bigint's and not integers, thanks for the hint!